# JavaScript code in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a question regarding code structure. The original code that this snippet is taken from works well:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
        ...
        ...
        $invalidField = 2;
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta ... />
<title>.../title>
<link rel = "icon" ... />
<link rel = "stylesheet" ... />
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function processServerResponse(){  
    var invalidField = <?php echo $invalidField; ?>;
    if (invalidField != 0){
        if (invalidField == 1){
            var errorMsg = "Please enter the required fields...";
        }
        else{
            var errorMsg = "Thank you for your interest.";
        }
        document.getElementById("serverReply").innerHTML = errorMsg;
        invalidField = 0;
    }
};
</script>

[if the above PHP code is placed here, the JavaScript function does not run]

</head>
<body onload = "processServerResponse()">
...
...
...
```

However, from my understanding, PHP code can be placed anywhere within HTML code *(but saved as PHP file of course)*. So, why does the JavaScript not run if the PHP block is moved down below it, just before the body block?

Comment: Which of the two blocks of php code are you meaning?

Comment: @iSofia Because, you use your variable before its defined.

Comment: Because then this line wouldn't have a value `<?php echo $invalidField; ?>;`

Comment: There'll be only one block of PHP code. If the PHP code is placed right at the top, as per the example, everything works well. But if the same block of PHP code were moved down, below the JavaScript block, the PHP code is still executed, but the JavaScript code is not.

Comment: Daedalus & Pitchinnate: You're right, but shouldn't the code still get executed? I even placed an ALERT within the function just to test, but it is not executed at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line:

```
var invalidField = <?php echo $invalidField; ?>;
```

use html + php code to output php variable into final html page, so this variable should be initialized *before* this code executed

if this variable is not initialized, this code become:

```
var invalidField = ;
```

which leads to javascript syntax error (check your browser's console), this is why this code is not parsed/executed by browser at all

this variable is initialized by php block above, so you need this php code in any place, but before ouput

also, it is better to use:

```
var invalidField = '<?php echo $invalidField; ?>';
```

note quotes, this will prevent js syntax errors

Comment: Yes, the variable will not be initialised if the PHP block is placed below; but even if the variable has not been defined, shouldn't the JavaScript function still run ONLOAD?

Comment: @iSofia it will, but as soon as variable is not initialized - this js code becomes invalid (it has syntax error then)

Comment: It works! You're a genius - thank you! And thanks to Daedalus & Pitchinnate as well. Really appreciate it guys.